# Gradle and Eclipse- "..:DependentProject" not supported in settings.gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle

I am trying to import a sibling project `tom-commons`. My project `budget_assistant` needs `tom-commons` as a dependency, and they are both in the same workspace folder, not nested. It works fine in Intellij IDEA and the command line. But Eclipse does not seem to like it.

[image]

I don't think it is liking the ".." relative path and Eclipse must think it is a folder nested under my project. Is there a way to resolve this dependency into an absolute URL?

Here is my `settings.gradle`

```
include ':..:tom-commons'
```

And here is my `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
    compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.8.7'
    compile 'net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile project(':..:tom-commons')
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir "src/main/java"
}

jar { 
    from configurations.compile.collect { entry -> zipTree(entry) }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this a bug to me. It isn't quite clear yet whether this is a bug in STS gradel tooling or in Gradle itself. I.e. either STS tooling is misinterpreting the info it gets from the tooling API or it is getting 'junk' from the tooling API. I can investigate the problem, but it would be helpful to have a small 'toy' project that demonstrates the problem. Would you mind raising a bug report on our issue tracker: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS

Comment: Okay I opened an issue as directed https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4114

Comment: And I put a simple project on GitHub that recreates this error https://github.com/thomasnield/gradle_eclipse_multiproject_bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are implicitly creating a project called ":.." and the Gradle tooling API directly reflects that in its project model as an "EclipseProject" who's name is "..". But. ".." is not a valid name for a project in an Eclipse workspace which causes the exception.

I still think this is a bug, in a sense. As we can put some blame on both Gradle tooling API for returning something illegal; and the tooling for not handling this 'junk' data more gracefully.

But really, I think you do not want a ":.." project. Rather you just want a ":ChildA" and ":ChildB" project which are direct children of ":" (in terms of project hierarchy), but are located as siblings in terms of where they reside on disk.

This kind of layout is most easily accomplished with 'includeFlat' (see [Gradle docs](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)) in settings.gradle.

In settings.gradle:

```
includeFlat 'ChildA','ChildB'
```

In build.gradle refer to children as ":ChildA" and ":ChildB" e.g:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':ChildA')
    compile project(':ChildB')
}
```

See my [changes to your sample on github](https://github.com/kdvolder/gradle_eclipse_multiproject_bug/commit/8833525f98af940de645820497b4bb55dbdec3fd).

Comment: Very interesting, I will take a look at this and mark your answer first moment I'm at a computer. Thanks for setting aside time for this.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a git/workspace setup. Can you take a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634318/gradle-double-tier-multi-project-in-eclipse