# Gradle- double-tier multi-project? In Eclipse with .git folders?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, gradle, egit

A few months back [I asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884176/gradle-multi-project-with-outside-projects) about multiprojects with neighboring project folder dependencies.

I have a similar problem but with one complication. In each "project" folder, I put the .git folder and the actual project folder. So it is the same structure except I have to move up and move down two levels.

```
|
 \ workspace
     |
      \
       MyProject
         |
         \
          MyProject //contains src and build.gradle
          .git
     |
      \
       DependencyA
         |
         \
          DependencyA //contains src and build.gradle
          .git
```

I have tried to put this into my settings.gradle file for `MyProject`

```
include '..:..:DependencyA:DependencyA'
```

and this dependency setup in my `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':..:..:DependencyA:DependencyA')
}
```

I get an error saying `Project with path ':..:..:DependencyA:DependencyA' could not be found in root project 'MyProject'`

I am suspecting I do not understand how `..` works and it is not like a Linux "move up one directory" command. What am I doing wrong? Or perhaps I'm just not mixing GIT and Gradle properly.

***UPDATE***

Eclipse is having issues with this even though I remedied the typo. [I'm having deja vu and dealt with this before and ultimately used flatMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990536/gradle-and-eclipse-dependentproject-not-supported-in-settings-gradle), but I don't know how to flatMap a double nested multi-project. It is having a bad time interpreting the `..`

Comment: The way you set it up works for me. Please check that your folder names match your include path. Where does your settings.gradle live?

Comment: doh! Yes there is a typo and fixing it addressed the issue. Now I got a separate issue with Eclipse not liking it.

Comment: I ended up abandoning Eclipse's Gradle plugin, and used the Gradle command line instead with `apply plugin: 'Eclipse'`